# How to hash a paragraph

Tags: python, hash

my code:

```
import hashlib

hashlib.sha384("mujtaba azar").hexdigest()
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "m:/M.AzAr/Personal/My
> Project/Python Project/Simpel Project/hash.py", line 3, in 
> hashlib.sha384("mujtaba azar").hexdigest() TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of the string must be specified before hashing, e.g. for utf-8:

```
hashlib.sha384("mujtaba azar".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
```